# Make text disappear after I hover over it

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I want to make my text disappear and keep it away when I hover over it, but I don't know how. Can you guys help me out?

This is my CSS

```
p:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
I want to be your <p>girl</p>friend.
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the text you want to disappear have a specific id and the outer text have a specific text as well.:

`<p id="text">I want to be your <span id="disappear">girl</span>friend.</p>`

CSS alone will not work for this, because once you hover the element to make it disappear, it will no longer be hovering and will just reappear. This will cause it to continually flicker. So for this, we'll need some Javascript:

```
var disappear = $("#disappear");
$("#text").hover(function(){
    disappear.hide();
}, function() {
    disappear.show();
});
```

This Javascript stores the `disappear` element as an object. It then waits for the `text` element to be hovered and "unhovered" over (the first parameter is for hover, the second is for "unhovering"). When `text` is hovered, `disappear` is hidden using `.hide();`. When `text` is unhovered, `disappear` is shown using `.show();`.

Here's a fiddle for it: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c4uoew4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to your "p" tag and then give the class:hover attribute, display: none;

```
HTML:
I want to be your <p class="disp">girl</p> friend.

CSS:
.disp:hover {
    display: none;
}
```